# Как получить два набора данных (Таблицы или Reader) из двух выборок SQL?

Tags: c#, c++, sql, sql-server, oledb

В *Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio* большой запрос возвращает все выборки. Как сделать что б после `Command.Execute` получить програмно все выбранные таблицы. Т.е.

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].p1  begin
   select 1 select 2,3   -- выборка
end
/*results:
1

2  3*/
```

Что б дало две таблицы а не одну. Да запрос можно "разделить" на два, но до тех пор пока нет связи между ними через локальные переменные.  Можно конечно и их передать, но Studio ловит две три таблицы из выполняемой хранимой  процедуры.

1) Пробовал OleDb - там дополнительных курсоров не получилось получить. Думаю что поддержка нескольких таблиц заложена в sqlncli.dll. 2) Возможно как-то можно средствами sql сделать такую выборку, что б сложить таблицы в таблицу (курсорное поле), или например с помощью sp_msforeachtable.

Comment: Рабочего С++ примера, к сожелению, пока что нету, как дойдут руки - напишу. Ответа + коментария к ответу достаточно что б понять как его написать. Если будет хороший другой ответ -приветствую. А ссылки на справочную информацию у меня уже есть. Даже там два способа один ADO другой oledb, я думаю oledb должно работать оптимальнее.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте поработать с объектом ADO Recordset [для С++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms677566(v=vs.85).aspx).

---

**Пример** работы с Recordset в VBA:

```
        Dim rsTree As ADODB.Recordset
        Dim rsTreeGrp As ADODB.Recordset
        Dim rsGrp As ADODB.Recordset
        Set rsTree = ExecuteRS("usp_pct_CatList", 2, 0, "") 
        Set rsTreeGrp = rsTree.NextRecordset()
        Set rsGrp = rsTreeGrp.NextRecordset()
```

*Процедура `usp_pct_CatList` возвращает три выборки.*

Comment: Да, точно, в c# это  `IDataReader.NextResult`

Comment: Для с++ вот он ответ через OleDB IMultiplyResults https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22410744/Get-the-record-count-by-C-and-OLEDB.html, АDO выходит надстройка над OleDB.