# Закрытый DataReader

Tags: c#, mysql, база-данных

Нужно получить несколько таблиц из Mysql БД и записать их в `DataSet`. Вернее это даже не таблицы а выборки из двух таблиц слитые в таблицу через `UNION`. В интерфейсе СУБД (WorkBench) запрос отрабатывает корректно поэтому приведу только код клиента :

```
DataSet dataset = new DataSet("Name");
//
internal static void GetInvestment(string order, string SType)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new 
MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                string query = @"SELECT ... FROM (...UNION ALL...) X
                            GROUP BY `Title` ";
                MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", order);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", SType);
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            if (reader.GetDecimal(3) > 0)
                            {
                                DataTable table = dataset.Tables.Add(SType);
                                table.Load(reader);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    BOX.ShowError(ex.Message, ex.Source);
                }
            }
        }
```

Должно получится несколько выборок, по одной согласно каждой `SType`, т.е. метод `GetInvestment` вызывается в цикле, каждый раз с новым `SType` однако сразу ловит исключение :

> Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed

По смыслу понятно что `reader` оказался закрытым после 1же таблицы но почему и как его держать открытым?

Comment: Не закрывать using-ом или close

Comment: @nick_n_a т.е. директива `using` закрывает `reader` ?

Comment: @Сергей закрывает, когда поток выходит из блока using. Так работает IDisposable

Comment: Да, точно, есть особенность -  вызов `Load` вызывает закрытие reader после обработки. Если вам нужно несколько таблиц - читайте в DataSet - вам среда автоматически туда добавит несколько таблиц DataTable(Ток запрос должен быть [пакетным](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/552182/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-reader-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-sql))

Comment: @nick_n_a спасибо, не знал про `Load` !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените:

```
using (MySqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
{
  if (reader.Read() && reader.GetDecimal(3) > 0)
  {
     DataTable table = dataset.Tables.Add(SType);
     table.Load(reader);
  }
}
```

Сколько таблиц должно создаться в результате одного вызова метода `GetInvestment`?

*Update*

> reader всегда читает на одну строку меньше. ... Из за чего это
>   происходит?

Это происходит из-за вызова `reader.Read()` до загрузки данных в таблицу. В таблицу грузятся данные от текущего положения курсора ридера до конца данных. А `reader.Read()` сдвигает курсор на одну запись от начала. Тут надо разобраться с логикой создания таблицы. Вы ее создаете по условию `reader.GetDecimal(3) > 0`, которое можно проверить только начав читать данные. Вам или придется читать данные два раза - в первый раз получая только одну запись (не знаю, как это делается в MySQL, в T-SQL - `TOP(1)`) и выполняя проверку `reader.GetDecimal(3)`, а второй раз - уже читая все данные для таблицы. Или - грузить все в таблицу без проверки, проверять значение поля с индексом 3 из первой записи таблицы, и, если проверка не проходит, удалять таблицу.

Comment: `Сколько таблиц ?` В одной таблице в `DataSet` после каждого вызова останется +1 или +0 таблиц. Зависит от `reader.GetDecimal(3) > 0`

Comment: @Сергей Вам не нужен цикл `while` в `GetInvestment`.

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрался.

Comment: Заметил ошибку - `reader` всегда читает на одну строку меньше. Запрос в Workbench возвращает 3 строки а в `table` попадает только 2. Из за чего это происходит?

Comment: @Сергей Добавил в ответ.

Comment: @Спасибо. Буду знать. Хотя уже через DataAdapter сделал